# Copying an Object in different ways

Tags: oop, design-patterns, ooad

I am looking for design principles/patterns to copy an object in different ways. For example, I have the following options to copy an object of type ACCOUNT class.

1) Clone Exactly

2) Clone All except credit details

3) Clone for Credit reversal (negate the values) etc..

In all the scenarios, the same object is cloned; but with different values based on the client's input.
I was thinking of the Prototype pattern; but it doesn't allow the client to control how the object should be copied.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: why you want to use a pattern/principle just to clone/copy an object?

Answer (score 0):

Prototype pattern or possibly Factory as the more generic solution.

Clone exactly is just a copy as we know it. The most common solutions are copy-by-value, copy-by-reference and the hybrid copy-on-write.

Clone all except credit details is - like "clone for credit" - instead the creation of a new object that is related to the original.

Whether you want to implement any of these on the concrete object, or in a Factory is really a matter of local conditions in your task.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning is not a simple concept. You have the traditional shallow copy or deep copy, but you can have anything in between. You can shallow copy some field of an object while deep copying ('recursive cloning') the others.

The particular cloning method is the responsibility of the application, that's why it can't be automated or auto-generated.

If you clone complex object graphs it's even possible that some fields will be updated by the parent class. So you can't even encapsulate everything in the clone method of one class.

I'm afraid you won't find specific cloning patterns what you describe, but the Prototype pattern with some extensions ('cloning flags') will be ok.